# Buscando un apellido en un campo con 2 apellidos en Mysql

Tags: php, formularios

Tengo una tabla con 4 campos: **Nro colegiatura**, **Apellidos**, **Nombres** y **Estado**.

Quiero hacer una búsqueda en el apellido y si por ejemplo busco solo los que se apellidan Velez, me liste la información de todos los que se apelliden Velez.

Tengo este form

```
<form name="consulta2" method="post" action="resultado1.php"> 
        <input placeholder="Buscar por Apellido Paterno:" type="text" name="busca" maxlength="25" class="input-search"><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Buscar">
        </form>
```

Y el proceso esta en:

```
$busca = $_POST['busca'];

$sql = "SELECT coleap, colenom, estado FROM psicologos WHERE coleap LIKE %$busca% "; 

echo $sql;

$result = mysql_query($sql);
//se despliega el resultado  
echo "<div align='center'>";
echo "<table style='border:1px solid #CCCCCC; width:80%';>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th style='font-family:Arial; border-right:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;  font-size:13px'>Apellidos</th>";
echo "<th style='font-family:Arial; border-right:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;  font-size:13px'>Nombres</th>";
echo "<th style='font-family:Arial; border-right:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;  font-size:13px'>Estado</th>";
echo "</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td style='font-family:Arial; border-right:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; font-size:13px'>" . $row[0] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='font-family:Arial; border-right:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; font-size:13px'>" . $row[1] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='font-family:Arial; border-right:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center; font-size:13px'>" . $row[2] . "</td>";

    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

> Pero no me funciona, o no me muestra nada o me muestra todo el listado
>   sin ningún filtro. ¿En que estoy errado?

Comment: Mientras esperamos que la edición de la pregunta sea aprobada, te comento un detalle que quisiera me aclararas: en tu consulta, parecen faltar las comillas simples que rodeen a tu palabra de búsqueda ¿has probado esta consulta en un cliente de Mysql, como phpmyadmin, por ejemplo?

Comment: **mysql_query**: Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en **PHP 5.5.0** y eliminada en PHP 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones **MySQLi** o **PDO_MySQL**. [Visitar](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el operador **SOUNDS LIKE** DE MySQL; del modo siguiente

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_name WHERE apellido SOUNDS LIKE "Velez";
```

> Que te auxiliará a buscar una coincidencia de la cadena de texto que
>   tu escribas, siempre y cuando esten parecidas auxiliandote también del operador LIKE

**Ejemplo con el operador %% y LIKE**

1. El operador % usado al final de la cadena de texto buscará la coincidencia al inicio de la cadena de texto
2. El operador % usado al inicio de la cadena de texto buscará la coincidencia al final de la cadena de texto

Los comodines %%, se usan cuando se quiere encontrar una o mas coincidencias dentro de la cadena de texto o numérica a comparar

> O también puedes hacer uso del operador del símbolo de porcentaje para
>   buscar coincidencias en la cadena de texto que le pases %%

```
SELECT * FROM tabla_name WHERE apellido LIKE "Velez%";

SELECT * FROM tabla_name WHERE apellido LIKE "%Velez";
```

Answer (score 0):

pon `%busca%` entre comillas simples.

```
$sql = "SELECT coleap, colenom, estado FROM psicologos WHERE coleap LIKE '%$busca%' ";
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta y bienvenido! mira por favor [answer]. Se pide que las respuestas, no solo sean la respuesta si no que contengan un poco de contexto y explicacion del problema en las mismas. Saludos!